# tf.data.Dataset.from_generator - TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a generator function that will take multiple inputs and outputs to pass to a model using a series of memory mapped numpy arrays (larger than available RAM). All preprocessing has already been performed and I just need to access these arrays in batches.

```
def generator_function(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, label1, label2):

    def generator():
        for input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, label1, label2 in zip(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, label1, label2):
            yield {"x1_train_data": input1, 
                   "x2_train_data": input2, 
                   "x3_train_data": input3, 
                   "x4_train_data": input4,
                   "x5_train_data": input5,
                   "x6_train_data": input6}, {"x1_train_label": label1, "x2_train_label": label2}

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, 
                                             output_types=({"x1_train_data": tf.float32, 
                                                            "x2_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                            "x3_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                            "x4_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                            "x5_train_data": tf.int64,
                                                            "x6_train_data": tf.float32},{"x1_train_label": tf.int64, "x2_train_label": tf.int64}),
                                            output_shapes=tf.TensorShape([50,150,150, 150, 150,9, 1,5]))
    dataset = dataset.batch(2)
    return dataset
```

When I attempt to fit the model:

```
model.fit(generator_function(np_array1, np_array2, np_array3, np_array4, mp_array5, np_array6, np_array7, np_array8), epochs=10)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence. Input has type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape'>.
```

I've tried referring the official documentation and other SO posts but haven't been able to find a solution that used both multiple inputs and multiple labels.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on Alexander's answer. the output_types and output_shapes is deprecated as of TF 2.12.0. Docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator)

The docs suggest using

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, 
            output_signature=({"x1_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,50),dtype=tf.float32), 
                        "x2_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,150),dtype=tf.float32),
                        "x3_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,150),dtype=tf.float32),
                        "x4_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,150),dtype=tf.float32),
                        "x5_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,150),dtype=tf.int64),
                        "x6_train_data": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,9),dtype=tf.float32)},
                        {"x1_train_label": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,1),dtype=tf.int64), 
                            "x2_train_label": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,5),dtype=tf.int64)}))
```

Exclude the None in the shapes if you are not batching

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple inputs and outputs in your models you have to make sure to follow the same naming scheme in your **output_types** and **output_shapes** :

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, 
                                         output_types=({"x1_train_data": tf.float32, 
                                                        "x2_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                        "x3_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                        "x4_train_data": tf.float32,
                                                        "x5_train_data": tf.int64,
                                                        "x6_train_data": tf.float32},{"x1_train_label": tf.int64, "x2_train_label": tf.int64}),
                                        output_shapes=({"x1_train_data": tf.TensorShape([50]), 
                                                        "x2_train_data": tf.TensorShape([150]),
                                                        "x3_train_data": tf.TensorShape([150]),
                                                        "x4_train_data": tf.TensorShape([150]),
                                                        "x5_train_data": tf.TensorShape([150]),
                                                        "x6_train_data": tf.TensorShape([9])},{"x1_train_label": tf.TensorShape([1]), "x2_train_label": tf.TensorShape([5])}))
```